# Ternary codes of countries in django_countries

Tags: python-3.x, django

I need to list the ternary codes of countries in django_countries but I can not reach the list

my import :

```
from django_countries import countries

...
def populate_countries():
    for country in list(countries):
        Country.objects.get_or_create(
        country_name=country.name,
        country_code=country.alpha3
        )
...

>>> AttributeError: 'CountryTuple' object has no attribute 'alpha3'
```

How can I reach them?

Comment: Please post the complete trace back…

Comment: @deceze
`
In [36]: countries[0].alpha3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-77fe0aaad132> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 countries[0].alpha3

AttributeError: 'CountryTuple' object has no attribute 'alpha3'

In [37]:
`

Comment: python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, app, auth, contenttypes, images, refresh_token, sessions, users
Running migrations:
  Applying app.0001_populate_countries...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
...
  File "backend/app/migrations/0001_populate_countries.py", line 12, in populate_countries
    country_code=country.alpha3
AttributeError: 'CountryTuple' object has no attribute 'alpha3'